# BootStrap not working with ie 8, ie9

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I hope your all can read this question before you mark it as duplicate question or vote down me.

Currently, I doing Bootstrap with asp.net C# based on this link 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table

I work on it and it working on IE10 but not IE9 and IE8. After I googled and found most of the people said include the response.js can settle everythings.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

But unfortunately it still not working in IE8 and IE9. And other people suggest me using this to solve the issue but still cant works.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

Any people got suggestion/solution to solve this issue? I guess this should be css not supported issue. Thanks!

this is fiddle for example:
https://jsfiddle.net/dwtr1eom/2/

Updated (14/7/2016)
I solved the issue for IE9 by modify this:

```
       {
            display: block;
            width:100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            float:left;
            clear:left;
        }
```

Keep looking for solution for IE 8, Thanks

Comment: Could you create a fiddle that re-creates this issue so we can see it directly?

Comment: @Will Ray I had create a fiddle, thanks!